# Grouping up a data to separate lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I am experiencing a bit of a logical conundrum right now. Here is the problem I am trying to solve

**The Problem**

I am reading in a PDB file and when it goes through the file it creates a list of all the chains in the file. The list looks something like this

```
 chainIdList = [A, E, D, F, G, H];
```

The length can vary.

I have another list of all the chainIds of every residue in the sequence the data is a dictionary that I made that looks like this

```
chainResidue = {"chainId" : chainId, "residueNumber" : residueNumber}
chainResidue = { "A", "4"}
```

So what I would like to do is iterate through the list of chainResidues and check to see if the chainResidue.chainId is in the chainList. If so then create a new list of the chainId matched and then append all the residueNumbers to that list.

If that makes sense?

So in the end it would look like

```
A = [ 4, 6, 7, 8, ... and so on];
E = [ 9, 10];
```

**The code so far**

```
for (var i = 0; i < chainResidue.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < chainList.length; ++j) {
        if (chainResidue[i].chainId === chainList[j]) {
           //Append value of the chainResidue[i].residueName into chainList[j] make a list of lists?
        }
    }
 }
```

**Sample Data**

```
ATOM   3434  CA  LEU Y  17      -3.567   5.653  33.836  1.00 28.21           C  
ATOM   3435  C   LEU Y  17      -3.114   6.290  32.530  1.00 31.33           C  
ATOM   3436  O   LEU Y  17      -2.020   6.873  32.474  1.00 26.01           O  
ATOM   3437  CB  LEU Y  17      -2.620   4.575  34.233  1.00 29.46           C  
ATOM   3438  CG  LEU Y  17      -2.610   4.263  35.705  1.00 33.42           C  
ATOM   3439  CD1 LEU Y  17      -1.430   3.363  35.960  1.00 40.68           C  
ATOM   3440  CD2 LEU Y  17      -2.351   5.483  36.559  1.00 40.12           C  
ATOM   3441  N   ASP Y  18      -3.926   6.263  31.454  1.00 30.62           N  
ATOM   3442  CA  ASP Y  18      -3.487   6.866  30.205  1.00 31.46           C
```

I am just pulling in the "Y" and the number it's numbers that correspond to it like 17 and 18.

Comment: please add some example data.

Comment: @NinaScholz does that help?

Comment: no, not really. i am interested in chainIdList and chainResidue with valid data. What are the result sets of `A` and `E`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this ES6 script:

```js
// Sample data
var chainIdList = ['A', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
var chainResidue = [
  {"chainId" : "A", "residueNumber" : 24},
  {"chainId" : "E", "residueNumber" : 18},
  {"chainId" : "A", "residueNumber" : 9},
  {"chainId" : "A", "residueNumber" : 15}
];

// Create the empty lists to start with, per letter
var chainIdObj = chainIdList.reduce( (obj, id) => (obj[id] = [], obj), {} );

// Populate those lists with residue numbers
var result = chainResidue.reduce( (res, obj) => (res[obj.chainId] ? res[obj.chainId].push(obj.residueNumber) : 0, res), chainIdObj); 

console.log(result);
```

#### Explanation of the code

There are two main phases:

1. Create an object that has a property for every letter in the input array. The property values are all set to empty arrays (since we have no processed anything yet).

`chainIdList.reduce` iterates over the input array and for each element it calls the function provided for it. The first argument of that function is always the result of the previous call. The first time, there is no previous call, and then it then starts with the empty object (`{}`) we provide as second argument to `reduce`.

The function passed to `reduce` looks like this:

```
(obj, id) => (obj[id] = [], obj)
```

This is in fact the newer notation, introduced by EcmaScript6 in 2015. In the "older" syntax, it would look like this:

```
function (obj, id) { return obj[id] = [], obj; }
```

The function body uses the comma operator, and together with the `return` it is really equivalent to this code:

```
 obj[id] = [];
 return obj;
```

So, taking it all together, the value of `obj` starts with `{}` and then in each iteration a property is defined for it. After the first iteration it is

```
 { 'A': [] }
```

... and returned to the `reduce` internals, so that it is passed as argument in the next iteration, etc. The object that is returned in the last iteration will be returned as return value of the whole `reduce` call.

So now we have `chainIdObj` equal to:

```
{
  "A": [],
  "E": [],
  "D": [],
  "F": [],
  "G": [],
  "H": []
}
```

2. The second phase is used to populate the arrays in the above structure. Again, it is a `reduce` to iterate; this time over `chainResidue`. The function that is executed for each object in `chainResidue` is:

   ```
   (res, obj) => (res[obj.chainId] ? res[obj.chainId].push(obj.residueNumber) : 0, res)
   ```

The first value of the first argument (`res`) is this time not initialised with `{}`, but with the result of the previous phase: `chainIdObj`. The above function checks if the `chainId` property value of the object we are looking at, matches with an entry in `res` (i.e. in `chainIdObj`). If so (`?`) the corresponding `residueNumber` is pushed to the array we just checked. In the other case (`:`) nothing should happen. But as the ternary operator requires the third expression, we just put `0`: anyway the expression's value is ignored, so this is just a syntax filler.

Finally, the comma operator is again used to make sure the `res` object is returned to the `reduce` internals, so we get it again in the next iteration. The final result is the result of the last iteration, and it is returned by `reduce`. It is assigned to `result`.

That is the thing that is output in console.

#### Functional Code

Some like to avoid variable assignments where possible, and restrict the use of them as function parameters. With the above elements, you can write such code like this:

```
console.log( chainResidue.reduce( 
   (res, obj) => (res[obj.chainId] ? res[obj.chainId].push(obj.residueNumber) : 0, res), 
                 chainIdList.reduce( (obj, id) => (obj[id] = [], obj), {} )));
```

Comment: Holy crap, that worked!!! Can you explain the code for me a little more? I would really like to know how this works

Comment: Added an explanation in my answer just now.

Answer (score 0):

While you already have an answer, i suggest not to use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), because it returns always the same object and not necessary.

```js
// Sample data
var chainIdList = ['A', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
    chainResidue = [{ chainId: "A", residueNumber: 24 }, { chainId: "E", residueNumber: 18}, { chainId: "A", residueNumber: 9 }, { chainId: "A", residueNumber: 15 }],    
    result = Object.create(null);

chainIdList.forEach(a => result[a] = []);
chainResidue.forEach(a => result[a.chainId] && result[a.chainId].push(a.residueNumber)); 
console.log(result);
```